# Query taking more time when executed in OBIEE Weblogic than on database

Tags: oracle, obiee

I have just started working on Oracle BI, I have a scenario where a dashboard when is loaded takes quite a while. At first I thought that the culprit behind such slow performance was database queries. But when the logs were viewed, queries which took hardly a second when executed on database (MDS) are showing 6 seconds as their execution time in Weblogics.

Below is the log of a simple query which takes almost 6s to execute on Weblogics and takes 897 milliseconds when executed on database.

```
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-0] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:3] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] ############################################## [[
-------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
44507272
SET VARIABLE QUERY_SRC_CD='ValuePrompt';SELECT "Project"."Project Type#1" saw_0 FROM "PLM PPM - Project Summary" ORDER BY saw_0
FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY


]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-23] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:3] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- General Query Info: [[
Repository: Star, Subject Area: PLMA, Presentation: PLM PPM - Project Summary

]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-2] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:3] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Logical Request (before navigation): [[

RqList  distinct 
    Dim - Project.Project Type as c1 GB
OrderBy: c1 asc

]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-48] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:5] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- The logical query block fail to hits or seed the cache in subrequest level due to   [[
 only one subrequest 


]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-51] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:5] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- The logical plan contains non-cacheable node, plan  [[
RqList <<82402988>> distinct 
    D1.c1 as c1 GB
Child Nodes (RqJoinSpec): <<82403017>>
    RqJoinNode <<82403016>> []
        (
            RqList <<82402995>>
                Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.PRJ_USRDEF_LIST0 as c1 GB
            Child Nodes (RqJoinSpec): <<82403009>>
                RqJoinNode <<82403008>> []
                    PPM_PROJECT_D AS Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D
            DetailFilter: Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.DELETE_FLG = 0
        ) as D1
OrderBy: c1 asc
node cache seed not inserted  due to multiple plan not cacheable

]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-50] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:5] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- The logical query seed the plan cache [[
plan 
RqList <<82403049>> [for database 3023:57:PLMA,57] distinct  /* FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY */ 
    Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.PRJ_USRDEF_LIST0 as c1 GB [for database 3023:57,57]
Child Nodes (RqJoinSpec): <<82403053>> [for database 3023:57:PLMA,57]
    RqJoinNode <<82403054>> []
        PPM_PROJECT_D AS Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D
DetailFilter: Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.DELETE_FLG = 0 [for database 3023:57]
OrderBy: c1 asc [for database 3023:57,57]

]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-16] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:5] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Execution plan: [[

RqList <<82402995>> [for database 3023:57:PLMA,57] distinct  /* FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY */ 
    Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.PRJ_USRDEF_LIST0 as c1 GB [for database 3023:57,57]
Child Nodes (RqJoinSpec): <<82403009>> [for database 3023:57:PLMA,57]
    RqJoinNode <<82403008>> []
        PPM_PROJECT_D AS Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D
DetailFilter: Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D.DELETE_FLG = 0 [for database 3023:57]
OrderBy: c1 asc [for database 3023:57,57]

]]
[2016-04-04T05:11:58.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-18] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:9:5] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Sending query to database named PLMA (id: <<82402995>>), connection pool named Connection Pool, logical request hash 44507272, physical request hash f82d8b03: [[

select D1.c1 as c1 from ( select distinct T286689.PRJ_USRDEF_LIST0 as c1
from 
     PPM_PROJECT_D T286689 /* Dim_PPM_PROJECT_D */ 
where  ( T286689.DELETE_FLG = 0 ) 
order by c1 ) D1 where rownum <= 65001

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-34] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Query Status: Successful Completion [[

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-26] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Rows 5, bytes 20060 retrieved from database query id: <<82402995>> [[

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-28] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Physical query response time 5 (seconds), id <<82402995>> [[

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-29] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Physical Query Summary Stats: Number of physical queries 1, Cumulative time 5, DB-connect time 0 (seconds) [[

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-24] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Rows returned to Client 5 [[

]]
[2016-04-04T05:12:04.000-07:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [TRACE:4] [USER-33] [] [ecid: 77bb740f357d872f:52e5f112:1522a219085:-8000-00000000004961ca,0:1:11] [tid: dbf7c700] [requestid: 157d0024] [sessionid: 157d0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Logical Query Summary Stats: Elapsed time 6, Response time 5, Compilation time 0 (seconds) [[

]]
```

Can anyone tell me how can I find the root cause of this issue.

Comment: This sentence in the log `Physical query response time 5 (seconds)` makes me think it is the physical query in the database... or at least the time to connect to the database. When you log in, are you logging in as the same user OBIEE runs as? Are you in the same db partition if you have more than one? Do you need to increase the number of connections in the connection pool?

Answer (score 1):

First the basics, how are you measuring the time the query takes? Are you using a chronometer (or firebug and the like) and measuring the time it takes to show results since when you open the dashboard page?
Or do you have User Tracking active and the execution time is the database time in the Usage Tracking table?
If it's the first option, then I suggest activating Usage Tracking and reviewing where the execution time is being spent. Maybe there's a lag between OBIEE Server and Database, or between the Server and Analytics...
For better understanding of OBIEE performance I suggest the series of blog posts of Robin Moffat on Rittman Mead blog. It's a lot of stuff to digest, and there's no simple answer to your question, but if you're working with obiee you better learn the components and how each one works.
Regards

Comment: And to add to a point, you did not mention if when testing directly in the database, if you are considering cache...

Comment: Sure thing Ana I will further dig in the blogs you have suggested. @Walter_Ritzel if by cache you mean that if I am compiling the query (using F9 in toad) which returns first 500 records or executing the query (using F5 in toad) which returns all the records. Then I am executing the query and it executes in milliseconds as mentioned in the question. :)